# What is the another way to Close the application other than Application.Exit()

Tags: c#

What is the another way to close the application in C#, without using the Application.Exit()

Comment: is this winforms/console app?

Comment: @George Application.Exit() has no effect in Console apps.

Comment: There are loads of ways, close all the forms, `Environment.Exit`.  It might help if you explained why you can't use `Application.Exit` though.

Comment: @Justin: Environment.Exit() is not coming in my application. What have to do?

Comment: @Abdul: Why not just `return`?

Comment: @Abdul: Why don't you answer the helpers questions?

Comment: @Abdul: ___Why don't you answer the helpers questions?___ Obviously you have been here many times since they've been asked. It _appears_ currently that you are greedy and impolite.

Comment: @phresnel: Where have to put the return code?

Comment: @phresnel: I didnt refresh the page, now only i saw the helpers questions. Sorry.

Comment: @Abdul: a) you should see a red notification icon in the upper left of your browser view, b) now that you have _recognized_ the questions, why don't you answer them? Do you think the others and I am any longer motivated to help you in the future?

Comment: @phresnel: Not like that, actually i didnt get any red notification icon in my browser.

Comment: @phresnel: I replied to all that who have questions.

Comment: Where is your answer to `is this winforms/console app?`? This is extremely relevant to the question and was the first question of all.

Comment: @phresnel: For that Jonathan pointed out Application.Exit() is possible only in the Windows Form and not on console application. Thats why i didnt answer to him.

Comment: @phresnel: Another thing is i am new to stackoverflow, i dont know what have to do, i just simply know how to ask questions that are all, and i am new to Computer languages also. I am the beginner.

Comment: a) It still unsolved whether you are targeting a console app or something else. It is clear to you, but not for us, as you refuse to just state it. It is not only of interest to him and you. b) Ask good questions which show that you have tried out some things yourself, and if there are questions regarding _your_ questions, try to answer them or ask for clarification. Whether you are a beginner or not is not even so relevant. Anyways, hope that didn't chill you away, take this as an advice for future questions, welcome on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @phresnel: That is Windows Application and thanks for you advice and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my question. Below code will solve my query,

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a console app you can use [`Environment.Exit(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx). The `0` parameter indicates this application ended with no errors. Obviously, if you're just exiting normally, you **should** probably just code so that normal program flow exits the `Main` method.

---

In Winforms, just close all forms using the [`Form.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) method.

Comment: Where have to put the Form.Close() method?

Comment: Wherever you'd like to close the form. Note that Form.Close() is the method, if the code is within your form then you'd just call `Close()` (somewhere within a method that gets called by your form, such as an event handler).

Comment: Tbh, requiring more thrust in the application than necessary just because the programmer is too lazy to use `return` is no good.

Comment: @phresnel, true, will edit my answer with this (i just answered question without noting issues).

Answer (score 1):

in winforms and wpf you can use this.close();

Answer (score 1):

In console applications, just `return` your path through back and from `Main`.

`Environment.Exit` would disrupt the program's flow control in potentially destructive manner and requires higher security settings than necessary. Imagine your customer is tech savvy, then asks you why your app needs this and that security flag, and you have to answer *"Because we use `Environment.Exit` instead of return."* Surely his next answer would be *"Why?"*. Do you know an answer that he/she couldn't counter with *"Can't you use `return`? If you have an unrecoverable exception, why don't you just not `catch` it?"*

Maybe `Environment.Exit()` has its place, but I didn't need it a single time in some years of C#.

For Winforms, use `Form.Close()` in your main-window, which will send a clean `Close`-event to the event-loop, without circumventing normal flow.

---

(sidenote: if you ever happen to use C++, calling `exit()` is almost always incorrect as it circumvents the whole RAII/destructor thing)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Form.Close()` on the primary `Form` (the one that was passed in through `Application.Run(Form)`).

Comment: Form.Close() is not coming, After i putting the "." close is not coming

Comment: On your main form use `this.Close()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Environment.Exit()  //Console Application
 Form.Close()    //WinForms Application
```

You can try checking this http://geekswithblogs.net/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx

and

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.402651.5

Comment: In my application Environment.Exit() is not coming.

Comment: Tbh, requiring more thrust in the application than necessary just because the programmer is too lazy to use return is no good. Answer should be paired with `return` at least. (no -1 because OP doesn't mention whether this is console-specific)

Comment: @Microprocessor: Change the From.Close() to Form.Close() in your explanation.